# Dynamically display imagebuttons in AsyncTask

Tags: android, dynamic, android-asynctask, android-view

So I am retrieving images from Parse and dynamically displaying them in a ScrollView LinearLayout, but I can't seem to add a clickListener or add them to the view. Here's what I have:

```
MyTaskParams params = new MyTaskParams(drinkList.get(j).getString("Name"), data, lPos, drinkList.get(j).getObjectId(), j);
                        MyTask myTask = new MyTask();
                        myTask.execute(params);
```

And then in I pass all my data and try adding the ImageButton to the view.

```
private static class MyTaskParams {
        String name;
        byte[] data;
        int lPos;
        String id;
        int j;

        public MyTaskParams(String name, byte[] data, int lPos, String id, int j) {
            this.data = data;
            this.name = name;
            this.lPos = lPos;
            this.id = id;
            this.j = j;
        }
    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<MyTaskParams, Void, MyTaskParams> {
        @Override
        protected MyTaskParams doInBackground(MyTaskParams... params) {
            String name = params[0].name;
            byte[] data = params[0].data;
            int lPos = params[0].lPos;
            String id = params[0].id;
            int j = params[0].j;

            Log.d("DOINBACKGROUND", data.toString());

            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
            btn = new ImageButton(getActivity());
            btn.setId(j);
            btn.setTag(name);
            btn.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            btn.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
            btn.setMaxHeight(100);
            btn.setMaxWidth(100);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new DrinkButtonListener(getActivity(), lPos, id));
            lLayout[lPos].addView(btn);

            return null;

        }
    }
```

Why can't I create a ClickListener or add the button to the view? 
I get the error:

"Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views"

Comment: Why are you using an AsyncTask object in that case ?

Comment: because I kept getting "memoryoutofbounds" errors

Comment: I think this is not going to disappear that way...

Answer (score 0):

Y ou can't touch the views in an other tread that the Main.

If you want to manipulate view you can post a runnable to a view like

```
myView.post(new Runnable(...));
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you're in doInBackground(), you're no longer in the UI Thread. In the prehistoric past, you could try to update the UI from the background, but it was Not A Good Thing To Do.

It was such a not good thing to do that they changed Android to throw an error if you tried.

You can work around it with specific methods. See

[Worker Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads) for more information.

I tend to think that there are more robust ways of doing what you're doing, but they're more complex. You've got the essential idea, though. You should take a long at the training class
[Sending Operations to Multiple Threads](http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/index.html), which may give you some more ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the UI by implementing the onProgressUpdate or onPostExecute methods in [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

In your case, you might want to use onPostExecute.

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<MyTaskParams, Void, Bitmap> {
    @Override
    protected MyTaskParams doInBackground(MyTaskParams... params) {
        String name = params[0].name;
        byte[] data = params[0].data;
        int lPos = params[0].lPos;
        String id = params[0].id;
        int j = params[0].j;

        Log.d("DOINBACKGROUND", data.toString());

        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bmp) {
        btn = new ImageButton(getActivity());
        btn.setId(j);
        btn.setTag(name);
        btn.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        btn.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
        btn.setMaxHeight(100);
        btn.setMaxWidth(100);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new DrinkButtonListener(getActivity(), lPos, id));
        lLayout[lPos].addView(btn);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code for **Log.e** and set values on button.

Here is the code.

```
yourclassname.this.runOnUiThread (new Runnable(){

            public void run() {

                NameUser.setText(name);
                Id.setText(email);
                cimg.setImageBitmap(btmp);
                add1.setText(address1);
                add2.setText(address2);
                City.setText(city);
                State.setText(state);
                Pincode.setText(pincode);
                Country.setText(country);
                Mobile.setText(mobile);
                Skills.setText(skills);

            }
        });
```